# Send mail task failure with error due to SMTP Connection

Tags: ssis, sendmail, msbi

I've created an SSIS package which runs perfect when scheduled as a job.Now I've have a requirement that a mail ought to be sent every time it runs stating if the package was successfully completed or failed.

I've created an SMTP Connection with server name as mx.xxxxxxxx(organization).I've neither checked windows authentication or Enable Secure Socket Layer Options(as suggested in various blogs).

The Job runs fine and sends mail when run manually but is failing when scheduled as a job.
I've tried running it by editing the command line as suggested by many but with no success.

Can you please suggest where I might be going wrong,
Below is the error:

Argument "SMTP" for option "connection" is not valid.  The command line parameters are invalid.  The step failed.

Comment: How are you running it manually?  Is it on the same server as when it is run by the job?

Comment: Hi Tab,If I run the SSIS Package manually from BIDS...It runs fine and delivers the mail.Yes the job runs on the same machine(Server) where the SSIS Package exists.

Comment: What I mean is, what if you run it manually (from SSMS) on the same server where it is when the job runs it?

Comment: It fails even if I run manually from SSMS...

Answer (score 0):

Since it fails when you run it from your production server, regardless of whether you run it manually or from the job, it is probably related either to connectivity (can your production server connect to the smtp server), or it could be permissions related, if you are using some kind of proxy account on the server that is different from the one you use in your local BIDS.